# How to round numbers inside of a object

Tags: javascript, object, rounding

How can I round numbers inside of a object like this:

```
{1: {x:10.76, y:50.44}, 2:{x:5.887, y:23.433}, ...}
```

I tried to do this using map but I guess map only works with arrays

```
obj.map(function(each_element){
    return Number(each_element.toFixed(0.1));
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Object.values` to get each inner object, then iterate over each of the `entries` and assign the new rounded number to the appropriate key of the inner object:

```js
const input = {1: {x:10.76, y:50.44}, 2:{x:5.887, y:23.433} };
Object.values(input).forEach((inner) => {
  Object.entries(inner).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    inner[key] = Math.round(val);
  });
});
console.log(input);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for` loop for that:

```js
var obj = {1: {x:10.76, y:50.44}, 2:{x:5.887, y:23.433}};

for(var keyOuter in obj){
  for(var keyInner in obj[keyOuter]){
    obj[keyOuter][keyInner] = obj[keyOuter][keyInner].toFixed(0.1);
  }
}
console.log(obj);
```